# Passing additional arguments to filter callback D3 & javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js, callback, closures

I am trying to refactor a javascript code that uses D3, i have ancountered a problem.
I will first post the code than ask the question.

```
add_link:function(e){
    // Get the source and target nodes
    var sourceNode = this.graph.nodes.filter(this.is_source_node)[0];
}
```

I need to pass the e argument from the wraping function to the callback function that automatically get 3 arguments by D3. 
The call back function looks like this.

```
is_source_node:function(n){
    return n.node.id === e.source.node.id;
}
```

I figured there should be some technique to do this using javascript core, or maybe a helper function that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "curry" that argument via `Function#bind`:

```
add_link:function(e){
    // Get the source and target nodes
    var sourceNode = this.graph.nodes.filter(this.is_source_node.bind(this, e))[0];
    // Change is here ------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

then:

```
// Change --------------vvv
is_source_node:function(e, n){
    return n.node.id === e.source.node.id;
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with a specific `this` value (which doesn't matter here) and any further arguments you give `bind`, followed by the arguments that it was actually called with.

A simpler example may be clearer:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  snippet.log("a is " + a + ", b is " + b);
}
foo(1, 2); // "a is 1, b is 2" as you'd expect

// Create a function that will call foo with 'first'
var f= foo.bind(null, 'first');

// Call it, passing in an argument
f('second'); // "a is first, b is second"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```